# How to pass normals to a Vertex Shader in GLSL when using glDrawElements

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader, lighting

I am building a simple 3D game for practice, and I am having trouble passing normals to my shader when using indexed rendering. For each face of a polygon, at each vertex there would be the same normal value. For a cube with 8 vertices, there would be 6 * 6 = 36 normals (since each surface renders with two triangles). With indexed drawing I can only pass 8, one for each vertex. This does not allow me to pass surface normals, only averaged vertex normals.

How could I pass 36 different normals to the 36 different indexes? Using glDrawArrays is apparently slow so I have elected not to use it.

Here is my shader:

```
#version 330

layout(location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 vertNormal;

smooth out vec4 colour;

uniform vec4 baseColour;
uniform mat4 modelToCameraTrans;
uniform mat3 modelToCameraLight;
uniform vec3 sunPos;

layout(std140) uniform Projection {
    mat4 cameraToWindowTrans;
};

void main() {
    gl_Position = cameraToWindowTrans * modelToCameraTrans * vec4(position, 1.0f);

    vec3 dirToLight   = normalize((modelToCameraLight * position) - sunPos);
    vec3 camSpaceNorm = normalize(modelToCameraLight * vertNormal);

    float angle = clamp(dot(camSpaceNorm, dirToLight), 0.0f, 1.0f);

    colour = baseColour * angle * 0.07;
}
```

And here is the code I am currently using to bind to the VAO:

```
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vertexArray);
    glBindVertexArray(vertexArray); 

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, polygonBuffer);

    // The position input to the shader is index 0
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(POSITION_ATTRIB);
    glVertexAttribPointer(POSITION_ATTRIB, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    // Add the vertex normal to the shader
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexNormBuffer);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(VERTEX_NORMAL_ATTRIB);
    glVertexAttribPointer(VERTEX_NORMAL_ATTRIB, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    glBindVertexArray(0);
```

This is my renderer:

```
glBindVertexArray(vertexArray);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, polygonVertexCount, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

Comment: The indices are shared between vertices, normals, and UV's.  You'll have to change your data to accommodate that.

Comment: Your answer along with @KillianDS solve it for me. Seems I need to stop trying to use 8 unique positions, instead I'll end up with 24, with 12 of those shared between two triangles.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> For a cube with 8 vertices, there would be 6 * 6 = 36 normals (since
>   each surface renders with two triangles).

Correct me if wrong, but I only see 6 normals, one per face. All vertices on that face will use the same normal.

> With indexed drawing I can only pass 8, one for each vertex. This does
>   not allow me to pass surface normals, only averaged vertex normals.

Here's where your reasoning fails. You do not just pass vertex locations to the shader, you pass a whole bunch of vertex attributes that make the vertex unique.

So if you use the same vertex location 6 times (which you'll often do), but with a different normal each time (actually two triangles will share the same data), you actually should send all the data for that vertex 6x, including duplicates of the location.

That being said, you don't need 36, you need `4*6=24` unique attributes. You have to send all vertices for each face separately because the normals differ and per face you have to differ between 4 positions. You could also see it as 8*3 because you have 8 positions that have to be replicated to handle 3 different normals.

So you'll end up with something like:

```
GLFloat positions[] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 
                        0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 
                        0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                        1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                        ...}
GLFloat normals[] = { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 
                      0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 
                      0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                      1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                      ... }
```

Note that while within `normals` and `positions` there is repetition, but that the combination of both at the same position is unique.

Comment: That's all great and everything, but I am not sure how to actually write the code for it. If I use glDrawElements, with 8 unique vertices (positions), and 36 indexes, how can I, in C++ code, send the correct normal values to each of those indexes? If you look at my code, you will see that exactly 8 unique position and normal values will be stored for a cube, and the indexes will generate 36 total vertices. That's the real part of my question, I understand fully well how many unique normals there are, I just need to know how to code it. Edit: I see that I need to change my data formal. Thanks!

Comment: I see no calculation of vertices whatsoever, only the buffers. You now will  have two buffers with 24 elements each instead of a buffer with 8 elements and one with 36 elements. and still an index buffer that has 36 indices.

Comment: Indeed. I had considered using 24 elements, but I convinced myself that there must be another way. Thank you for opening my eyes. I have accepted your answer. I thought I might have been missing some knowledge of some function, or some understanding of graphics, but really it was a matter of my own stubbornness and desire to find some kind of optimisation that never existed. This has helped me a lot.